# Retrieve Backbone Model value

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Is there a more efficient way of writing the statement below to access Backbone Model value?

```
self.model.attributes.person.attributes.personName
```

Also while the above works fine in a JS file, it does not work within my HTML template file

```
<%= self.model.attributes.person.attributes.personName %>
```

I use below code to call template;

```
this._initAndRenderModal(myModalTemplate, {
    person: this.model.toJSON()
});
```

How do I make it retrieve value within my HTML file as well?

Comment: Could you show the code that renders your template?

Answer (score 1):

Show more code, please. What is `person`? If it's a complex/nested *backbone* model (like `person` has `person` relation) then you can try this:

```
var name = model.get('person').get('personName');
```

You can use `model.get('propertyName')` to access model's properties.
When you call

```
this.template({model: templateData})
```

it is expected that you export `model` object as a reference to your template data so you would write it like this inside your template:

```
<%= model.get('property') %> <-- given that model is a backbone Model
```

or

```
<%= model.get('complexProperty').partOfTheComplexProperty %> <-- given that model is a backbone Model
```

or

```
<%= model.anythingYouWant %>
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends entirely on how you render it, but this should work:

```
_.template('<%= model.attributes.person.attributes.personName %>', { model: self.model });
```

I would also recommend using `toJSON` instead of accessing the attributes: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON

Answer (score 0):

To get name you may use (read more about `get`: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get)

```
self.model.get("person").get("personName")
```

To render the template correctly it should be

```
<%= person.attributes.personName %>
```

as you pass `this.model.toJSON()` to it - there's no need to point to the model itself.